# Sudden Issue with Chrome on PythonAnywhere - But just from Scheduled Task

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, pythonanywhere

For the past year or so, I have had a scraper run every morning. It had been functioning wonderfully but suddenly, this morning, I get this error:

> `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591071 (0b695ff80972cc1a65a5cd643186d2ae582cd4ac),platform=Linux 5.13.0-1017-aws x86_64)`

I have a manual button which triggers the same program on the web app that I have installed as a way to troubleshoot my software. I ran my app from this button and it functioned properly.

I then decided to reload the web-app and reset the scheduled tasks so it would be triggered a few minutes later yet I got the same error.

I am simply troubleshooting my web-app now and I am curious if something was updated overnight that may have only effected the way the scheduled task function.

Thanks

Comment: have you confirmed chrome version and driver version matching? because chrome may update frequently.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that was a possibility, but I am not sure how it would function at all if that were the case.  The program functions when manually called but not when it is triggered from a chron call.

Comment: Make sure that you have all the chrome options from the example https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/selenium set: "--no-sandbox” "--headless" and "--disable-gpu"

Comment: Thank you. Yes, those are the options I have set in my program.

Oddly enough, without any code changes on my part, the code worked automatically as it usually does this morning. 

Yet I am left with the question as to why this problem happened yesterday and not today. 

I suspect something from the scheduled task of pythonanywheres’ chron cycle had something to do with this but I do not know how to confirm this. The error codes did not offer any useful clues.